# Accidentally used git reset

Tags: git, commit

I accidentally ran

```
git reset
```

in my project folder. Now when attempting to run "git add ." no changes appear and then 'git commit -m '(message)'", it will keep displaying the code below, even after I make different changes.

How can I alleviate this issue?

```
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/FriendAdder$1.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/FriendAdder$2.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/FriendAdder$3.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/FriendAdder.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/ListOfFriends$1.class

#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/ListOfFriends$FriendL
istAdapter$ViewHolder.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/ListOfFriends$FriendL
istAdapter.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/ListOfFriends$Message
Receiver.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/ListOfFriends.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging$1
.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging$2
$1$1.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging$2
$1.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging$2
.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging$3
.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging$4
.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging$M
essageReceiver.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/PerformingMessaging.c
lass
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/toolBox/ControllerOfF
riend.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/androidChatter/toolBox/MessageContro
ller.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/GroupChat$1.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/GroupChat$FriendListAdapter
$ViewHolder.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/GroupChat$FriendListAdapter
.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/GroupChat$MessageReceiver.c
lass
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/GroupChat.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/R$array.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/TestChat$1.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/TestChat$FriendListAdapter$
ViewHolder.class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/TestChat$FriendListAdapter.
class
#       deleted:    bin/classes/com/example/feastapp/TestChat$MessageReceiver.cl
```

...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git add .` does not stage file deletions.  Try `git add -u .`, which will stage deletions (but will not stage new files).

If your Git version is new enough, it will support `git add -A .`, which will stage all new files, deleted files, and modified files at once (effectively updating the index to exactly match the working tree, excluding ignored files).

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I used git add -u ., then commited and restarted computer, now it works fine like it did when I used git add ., thanks

Comment: @Eatlon There is never any need to restart your computer when working with Git, unless a Git software upgrade requires it (which would only happen on Windows).